# error: package does not exist android google mobile backend starter

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-gradle-plugin

There are a few similar questions on here but I am having trouble finding a solution.

I am using the google mobile backend starter https://cloud.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/ and everything works until I want to try and send notifications from GCMintentService.java. If I call

```
Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
```

I get an error that MyActivity in the App module does not exist. I am pretty sure I should add something like

```
compile project(':app')
```

to the gradle dependances of the core module that holds GCMintentService.java but if I do I get an error saying that app is not a library?

Here is the core module gradle dependancies

```
dependencies {
    compile('com.google.cloud.backend:mobilebackend:v1-1.19.0-SNAPSHOT') {
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client:1.19.0'
    compile('com.google.http-client:google-http-client-android:1.19.0') {
        exclude(group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android')
        exclude(group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', module: 'httpclient')
    }
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-jackson2:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.1.3'
    compile 'org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.9.13'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.+@aar'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.4.52'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `app` project isn't a library (if it uses `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` instead of `apply plugin: 'com.android.library'`), then other modules can't depend on it. You can only depend on libraries, not application modules.

You may need to take your common code that everything depends on and break it out into a separate module that both your core module and your app module can depend on.

Comment: Thanks. I can't move the common code as all I am trying to do is call an app activity (which is `apply plugin: 'com.android.application'` as you thought) from a backend library. Is there any way to call an app module activity intent from a library? The backend library module handles all the messaging of the app and its from here that I would also like to generate a notification with an intent. Maybe this needs to be a whole new question. I have marked your answer correct as it answered my original question about the error

Comment: Another question is the way to go. You should be able to fire an intent from a library -- the coupling for intents is pretty loose and you won't hit a lot of library dependency issues if you structure it well.